# what is this error SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails

Tags: php, laravel

I have a code in `laravel`, but I cannot get it to work since I am getting a `SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation:` error explained in detailed below.

**This is the code**

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('tags', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->timestamps();
    });

    Schema::create('section_tag', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->integer('section_id')->unsigned()->index();
        $table->foreign('section_id')->references('id')-> on('tags')-> onDelete('cascade')-> onUpdate('cascade');
        $table->integer('tag_id')->unsigned()->index();
        $table->foreign('tag_id')->references('id')-> on('sections')-> onDelete('cascade')-> onUpdate('cascade');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}

public function down()
{
    Schema::dropIfExists('tags');
    Schema::dropIfExists('section_tag');
}
}
```

**and this is the error I get**

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a 
child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`book`.`section_tag`, CONSTRAINT 
section_tag_section_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`section_id`) REFERENCES `tags` 
(`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE) (SQL: insert into `section_tag` 
(`section_id`, `tag_id`) values (28, 1))
```

help me please

Comment: Please edit the question and explain what you want to do with the code

Comment: Please feed that error message to a websearch. Further, extract the actual SQL statement being executed. Then, if you still have questions left, provide a minimal example (Hint: It will only consist of SQL code, this has nothing to do with PHP or Laravel).

Answer (score 0):

okay from what i have seen so far it seems you are mixing up sections and tags in your schema. try changing the schema for section_tag to

```
 Schema::create('section_tag', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->integer('section_id')->unsigned()->index();
    $table->foreign('section_id')->references('id')->on('sections')->onDelete('cascade')->onUpdate('cascade');
    $table->integer('tag_id')->unsigned()->index();
    $table->foreign('tag_id')->references('id')->on('tags')->onDelete('cascade')->onUpdate('cascade');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

then also verify that section with id of 28 and tag with id of 1 exists because from the error the constraint is failing because one of them does not exist. hope it helps.